# GPU running underclocked / under normal speed?

Tags: performance, power-supply, gpu, overclocking, performance-tuning

I have tried to overclock my card. Seemingly it worked, and the GPU-z shows the OC speed (see GPU3.png). However, current readings are REALLY far from the normal speed of the GPU. That's what I can't figure out. I mean... it runs way too slow compared to the results I have found.

Pictures: (click to zoom in)

**Counter-Strike Source with fps_max turned off**

[image]

**Furmark's burn-in test**

[image]

**GPU-Z showing the OC values**

[image]

**Due to Brian's comment, 91% of fan speed. No effect. Still underclocked.**

[image]

I have a fairly decent (I think) PSU. A Corsair Enthusiast Series 750W v2.
The GPU is: **Zotac AMP2 GTX 260^2**
The power pins are also connected. Any idea? :-/

**Update:**

I've checked "GPU-Shark". It says, my GPU is in the State 3. I'd need State 0. The highest performance.

**Update 2:**

Guess I'm on the right track! [There is an application](http://somemorebytes.com/wp/index.php/software/nvpmmanager/) (God, or whoever ... bless the author), which lets you choose the power state by hand. Thus I have the normal speeds after setting it to Power. (*WARNING*: Select APPLY & Reboot. My OpenGL drivers crashed right after I used "Apply Instantly".) Anyway, so far so good! If this works, I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Looks like you have set a 60C max temperature and once it hits that it throttles back. Set the fan to 100% and run the test again to check.

Comment: Nope, question edited. The card became loud as hell, gpu stayed under 60C. But nothing, the mhz won't change a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PowerMizer Manager](http://somemorebytes.com/wp/index.php/software/nvpmmanager/) is the solution!
It can set your NVidia card into any power state, with an ease of click. Or with a reboot, that's a bit safer. Still, it's really convenient to use.